# Stop connection with IP after X packets

Tags: networking, iptables

There is a communication between my machine and a server (10 packets), and i'm trying to control it packet by packet.
How can I stop all communication after x packets ? (1-9 in my case)

I tried to use `tshark -c 2 host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and then cut the communication but it is too slow and let some packets through.

Additionally, is it possible to slow down this communication drastically, let's say to 1 packet per second ?

Comment: You need to provide more information of what you are trying to do. tshark does not stop communication it is recording it. Which communication would you like to stop?

Comment: You can surely do something tinkering with the [connbytes match](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iptables/iptables-extensions.8.en.html#connbytes). For the 2nd part, same advice as Winnie Tigger. `tc` might be used to add latency, but latency and speed isn't the same depending on how the communication is done.